# no signed_request on FIRST view via page tab

Tags: view, request, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a problem with my page tab.
When I access the app via the page tab the first time (e.g. logout, change browser, delete all cookies), I don't get the signed_request.
Here's (a part of) my code (I'm using the newest PHP SDK):

```
require_once ('facebook.php');
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                          'appId' => $app_id,
                          'secret' => $app_secret,
                          'cookie' => true
                     ));



$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$page_id = $signed_request['page']['id'];
```

$page_id is empty the first time I open the page tab. When I click the page tab again, everthing's fine and $page_id gets populated.

What am I doing wrong?
I found possible solutions on stackoverflow, but they don't work for me:
"signed_request for Canvas" is enabled and my page tab url ends with "tab.php".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try printing out all of the page's request parameters; do a `print_r($_REQUEST)` and see what you get when you first click the tab.

Comment: I've done what you asked, and this is what happens: a milisecond, this appears: `Array ( [signed_request] => dh6N5THZP...)`. Then it gets redirected, and then the array is empty... I get: `Array()`. The second time I click the page tab, everything's fine and the array gets populated again. Any ideas how to fix this problem? Info: I don't use redirects in my script. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
I included a file to get the user's timezone (based on the machine time, not facebook).
In this file, there's :`window.location = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`
This probably causes facebook to lose the signed_request on first visits.
Deleting the included php-file fixes the problem... now I only have to find a way to make the timezone work within facebook.